# Can I open an Offline Maps App with a link pointing to a GPS Position?

Tags: skmaps, garmin, tomtom, osmand, sygic

I want to generate a link with a gps position so that, when clicked, the Offline-maps-app (TomTom, Garmin, Sygic, Scout/Skobbler, Osmand, Locus, Maps.me, or any other) opens and shows the location, similar to http://maps.google.com/?q=latitude,longitude, but it should open in the app so that the offline maps are used.

I found out how to make such links for Google, MapQuest, Scout, Waze and here, but these all need internet access.

So, there are two questions:

1. Is it possible to provide a mere text that will be recognised as link (like a text starting with `http://`) and open an app?
2. if yes, are there offline-maps that can be opened by such a link and show a specific location?

Answer (score 0):

[Geo URI's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) can be used in HTML, and they should work on Android. Such a link looks like this, with the latitude and longitude:

```
<a href="geo:38.62464092991612,-90.18476128578186">go here</a>
```

Such a link will (should) be opened by any any Android maps app (assuming they developer has programmed the app to open such links). See [here](http://www.smick.net/notebook/how-to-link-to-a-gps-coordinate-on-a-webpage-using-geo-url/) for more info, and a link you can click to see if it works with your offline maps app.

Conceptually, they're sort of like `tel:` links.. a link doesn't have to point to a web address, after all.

That said, OSMand at least also captures and opens Google maps links, too.